# scala + slick-pg + implicit

Tags: scala, slick-3.0, slick-pg

I tried to add column based on example [slick-pg example][1]

Also added to the class table implicite

```
 implicit val pointFormat = MyFormats.geometryFormat[Point]
```

but have a compile error

```
could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point]
```

What I have done wrong? could you please give work example ?
                               ^

BR!

Answer (score 1):

What I have working for me is something in the following setup:

First, my table declaration:

```
 class EventTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Event](tag, "event"){
   def uid = column[String]("uid", O.PrimaryKey, O.Length(36))
   def userUid = column[String]("user_uid")
   def location = column[Point]("location")
   def start = column[LocalDateTime]("start")
   def end = column[LocalDateTime]("end")
   def visible = column[Boolean]("visible")
   def attending = column[Int]("attending")
   def required = column[Int]("required")
   def createdAt = column[LocalDateTime]("created_at")

   def * = (uid, userUid, location, start, end, visible, attending, required, createdAt) <>
      (Event.tupled, Event.unapply)
 }
```

I need to extensions: java8 time support (LocalDateTime) and geo stuff (Point). This is reflected in my `build.sbt` - I use version 0.11.0 for slick-pg:

```
"com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg"                             % slickPgV,
"com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg_jts"                         % slickPgV,
"com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg_date2"                       % slickPgV,
```

Now, the driver declaration:

```
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._

trait ExtendedPostgresDriver extends ExPostgresDriver
  with PgArraySupport
  with PgDate2Support
  with PgRangeSupport
  with PgHStoreSupport
  with PgSearchSupport
  with PgPostGISSupport
  with PgNetSupport
  with PgLTreeSupport {

   override val api = MyAPI

   object MyAPI extends API with ArrayImplicits
                            with DateTimeImplicits
                            with PostGISImplicits
                            with NetImplicits
                            with LTreeImplicits
                            with RangeImplicits
                            with HStoreImplicits
                            with SearchImplicits
                            with SearchAssistants {
   implicit val strListTypeMapper = new SimpleArrayJdbcType[String]("text").to(_.toList)

  }
}

object ExtendedPostgresDriver extends ExtendedPostgresDriver
```

So, take the java 8 time stuff. You can notice that the driver uses `PgDate2Support`, which then allows me the usage of the implicit `DateTimeImplicits`. By importing the `ExtendedPostgresDriver.api._` in my class of interest, I can then have the table definition use the `LocalDateTime` type that I need.

Same thing for `Point`: `PgPostGISSupport` -> `PostGISImplicits` -> `Point`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

When writing the integration with the PostgresDriver following [this](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) instructions add `with PostGISImplicits` in the object that overrides `api` (this trait is not included in the example).